# MySQL rationale behind "Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause"

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-delete

In MySQL, I cannot reuse a table in a predicate, if I am executing a `DELETE` or `UPDATE` on the same table. For instance, this is not possible:

```
DELETE FROM story_category WHERE category_id NOT IN (
--          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ deleting from this table...

SELECT DISTINCT category.id FROM category 
       INNER JOIN story_category ON category_id=category.id);
--                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ... prevents using the same table in predicates
```

The above example was taken from [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45494/521799), where the accepted answer and many other answers point out that there is a trick you can use by nesting the subquery into another subquery to trick MySQL into not recognising the table reuse:

```
DELETE FROM story_category
--          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
WHERE category_id NOT IN (
    SELECT cid FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT category.id AS cid FROM category 
        INNER JOIN story_category ON category_id=category.id
--                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ apparently no longer considered the same table
    ) AS c
)
```

Now, this workaround and the fact that it is even possible raise two big questions:

- The error checking is obviously not well implemented. A simple query transformation, and MySQL no longer recognises a situation that it tries to forbid for (hopefully) a good reason.
- Because there *probably is* a good reason, it *probably isn't* a good idea to work around this limitation.

I suspect that the reason for preventing such access in predicates is related to some guarantees that MySQL tries to establish with respect to ACID-ness. I'm afraid that if working around this limitation, I might corrupt my data or generate funny race conditions in edge-cases.

Unfortunately, [the MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) is not very explicit with respect to the rationale of this error:

> Currently, you cannot update a table and select from the same table in a subquery.

#### So, my question is:

What are the reasons why MySQL disallows this very common idiom where the table from an `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statement must not be referenced in any predicates?

Comment: The workaround works, not because of a "lack of error checking," but because using that construct materializes the inner query into an anonymous temporary table that's deleted when the query finishes... which is, of course, no longer the same table.  There is no harm in using the workaround as long as your queries are written intelligently, bearing in mind the underlying implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. That's interesting, although I would say that a more clever implementation of MySQL's query optimiser would do that for me. I find it a bit frightening, that there is an implicit temporary table in some cases, and not in other cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workaround is [suggested in the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subquery-restrictions.html), where it is explained that it works because the data is [materialized](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subquery-materialization.html) into a temporary table, as an optimizer "trick" for better performance. Since it's documented, I don't think there are any caveats in using it.

The "minimal" example of the workaround in the documentation is:

```
UPDATE t ... WHERE col = (SELECT * FROM (SELECT ... FROM t...) AS dt ...);
```

I too cannot find an explanation to why a simple UPDATE from subquery wouldn't work in MySQL, but this materialization workaround makes me think it has something to do with sorting out locking conflicts: you can't get an exclusive lock for a row UPDATE because it already has a shared lock for SELECT. When the SELECT comes from a second, "materialized" temporary table, there is no conflict.

That said, I admit this shouldn't make much sense since InnoDB documentation [explains](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-storage-engine.html) in detail that it supports tuple multiversioning and all four lock isolation levels, so this kind of operation should be supported as it is in PostgreSQL, Oracle and others.

Maybe the error message it gives out is a remaining failsafe from the MyISAM implementation since it only supports full table locks, but I wouldn't know why it should be in place for other engines.