# Subquery inside an update to set multiple values

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I want to move a DateTime of a record by using `update().set()`. When I try the [given example in the jOOQ docs for using a subselect](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/update-statement/) I found that I needed to cast to a `Row2` type because I want to set two variables. With this, the query gets build in an unusual way *(or at least not according to what I expect of the query given the example in the jOOQ docs)*:

```java
public static void moveEventStart(final LocalDate previousEventStart, final LocalDate newEventStart) {
    final Days changeInterval = Days.daysBetween(previousEventStart, newEventStart);
    ActivityTbl a = ACTIVITY.as("a");
    ActivityTbl a2 = ACTIVITY.as("a2")

    jooq()
        .update(a)
        .set(
            (Row2) row(a.START, a.END),
            select(
                 models.Jooq.dateAdd(a2.START, changeInterval.getDays(), DatePart.DAY),
                 models.Jooq.dateAdd(a2.END, changeInterval.getDays(), DatePart.DAY))
            .from(a2)
            .where(...))
        .where(...)
        .execute();
}
```

The dateAdd function is build like this:

```java
public static Field<Date> dateAdd(TableField<?, LocalDateTime> field, int interval, DatePart datePart) {
    String unit;
    switch (datePart) {
      case YEAR:
        unit = "YEAR";
        break;
      case MONTH:
        unit = "MONTH";
        break;
      case DAY:
        unit = "DAY";
        break;
      case HOUR:
        unit = "HOUR";
        break;
      case MINUTE:
        unit = "MINUTE";
        break;
      case SECOND:
        unit = "SECOND";
        break;
      default:
        unit = "";
    }
    return DSL.field(
        "DATE_ADD({0}, INTERVAL {1} " + unit + ")", SQLDataType.DATE, field, DSL.inline(interval));
  }
```

Produces:

```sql
update `Activity` as `a` 
set(`start`, `end`) = (
    select * from (
        select 
            DATE_ADD(`a2`.`start`, INTERVAL 1 DAY), 
            DATE_ADD(`a2`.`end`, INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
        from `Activity` as `a2` 
        where (...) as `t`
    ) 
where (...)
```

Why does jOOQ build a `select` on top of the already given `select`? And how do I make this work, so it sets the multiple values according to the given select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The syntax isn't supported by MySQL

MySQL doesn't support this syntax yet. You can see that on the Javadoc of jOOQ's [`UpdateSetFirstStep.set(Row2, Select)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/UpdateSetFirstStep.html#set(org.jooq.Row2,org.jooq.Select)) method, which lists these dialects as supported:

```java
@Support({ASE,AURORA_POSTGRES,BIGQUERY,COCKROACHDB,DB2,H2,HANA,HSQLDB,INGRES,ORACLE,POSTGRES,SNOWFLAKE,SQLSERVER,SYBASE})
```

jOOQ could emulate the syntax:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/10522 (Using `UPDATE .. FROM` for uncorrelated subqueries)
- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/10523 (By splitting the correlated subquery into two)

Both of these emulations aren't available yet as of jOOQ 3.15

#### If the syntax was supported, why the extra derived table?

If the syntax was supported, then the additional derived table is a workaround implemented by jOOQ for a limitation in MySQL, where an `UPDATE` or `DELETE` query cannot reference the DML statement's target table from within a correlated subquery (but magically, this limitations disappears when nesting the correlated subquery one level in a derived table). See:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6583
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subquery-restrictions.html
- [MySQL rationale behind "Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23853453/521799)